# Find the fourier transform of $e^{-ax^2}\cos(bx)$

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I am trying to find  the Fourier transform of the function $e^{-ax^2}\cos(bx)$.
I am changing $\cos(bx)$ to its exponential form but after that I am getting stuck: can you guide me showing how to find this Fourier transform?

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: Can you do the Fourier transform of $\exp(-a(x-c)^2)$ and how would that help with your problem?

Comment: Hint: $$ e^{-ax^2+ikx} = e^{-a(x-\frac{ik}{2a})^2 - \frac{k^2}{4a}} $$